# Catch browser crash with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with `ChromeDriver` to get information from a range of web pages. Every once in a while (there is no rhyme or reason to this), the automated instance of Chrome will hang, and I see console output such as:

```
[1220:8276:1106/115700.618:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:8276:1106/115700.623:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:1836:1106/115707.077:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:9800:1106/115708.149:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:10780:1106/115708.153:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:20872:1106/115714.815:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:2840:1106/115714.817:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
[1220:916:1106/115723.138:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(843)] Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.
```

At that point, clearly I am no longer able to get the page content, but there is also no internal exception generated in Selenium, therefore I can't handle the problem.

What's an approach I can use to detect when this issue occurs, and re-start the data acquisition from scratch?

Comment: Does your script keep working, or does it crash?

Comment: @GregBurghardt script is still alive. Chrome hangs, and just stays that way, and the console output above is all I see.

Comment: Which version of chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: It matches the version of installed Chrome (ChromeDriver is 86.0.4240.22) - I've verified that I am using the correct version. The error is also sporadic - sometime it shows and sometimes it doesn't. @GregBurghardt

Comment: By "sporadic" you mean it hangs on random lines of code, or is there a particular line that it hangs on?

Comment: @GregBurghardt completely unrelated to any lines of code. It seems like the issue is entirely related to ChromeDriver and not the Python script.